# Show that if $0<x< \frac{1}{2} \pi$, then $0<\cos x<\frac{\sin x}{x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Apostol (Calculus, pp. 118) says; "If $0<x< \frac{1}{2} \pi$, then $0<\cos x<\frac{\sin x}{x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}$". But where I can be a proof?

Comment: Hint: prove and use `0 < sin x < x < tan x` for `0 < x < π / 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the mean value theorem,

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{\sin x - \sin 0}{x} = \cos c_x$$

for some $c_x \in (0,x).$ Because $\cos$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi/2],$ we have $\cos x < \cos c_x,$ giving the first inequality. The second inequality is the same as

$$\frac{\sin x \cos x}{x} < 1.$$

That equals $(\sin 2x)/(2x),$ and because $\sin u < u$ for all $u>0,$ we have the second inequality.